# Upload to Google Drive not working using oauth PlayGround (java)

Tags: java, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

I want to use google drive api to upload some files to my drive using java
The thing is that the upload is successfull but when i open my drive i can't find the file so i've edited the permission and added my email (to share it with me) but i can't download the file there is just the name of the upload any idea why ?

```
public static void connect() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    UL.debug("Creating HTTP_TRANSPORT & a JSON_FACTORY");
    HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

    UL.debug("Login-in with credentials");
    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE))
            .createScoped(Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE));

    UL.debug("User: " + credential.getServiceAccountUser() + " ID: " + credential.getServiceAccountProjectId());
    UL.debug("Creating Drive Instance");
    DRIVE_SERVICE = new Drive.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName("Backup")
            .build();

}


public static void upload() throws IOException {
    UL.debug("Creating file metadata");
    File fileMetadata = new File();
    fileMetadata.setName("Test");
    fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/rar");

    UL.debug("creating new filepath");
    java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File(DATA_FOLDER, "test3.rar");

    UL.debug("Creating file content (rar)");
    FileContent rarContent = new FileContent("application/rar", filePath);

    UL.debug("Pushing the file to drive !");
    Drive.Files.Create upload = DRIVE_SERVICE.files().create(fileMetadata, rarContent);
    upload.getMediaHttpUploader().setProgressListener(new FileUploadProgressListener());
    upload.setFields("*");

    File e = upload.execute();

    UL.debug("Push success: " + e.getId() + " " + e.getName() + " " + e.getMimeType());

    Permission newPermission = new Permission();

    newPermission.setEmailAddress("eaglezledozo@gmail.com");
    newPermission.setType("user");
    newPermission.setRole("writer");
    DRIVE_SERVICE.permissions().create(e.getId(), newPermission).execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### You are performing an upload with a service account

The way you doing it, the file will be uploaded to the service'accounts Drive - not to yours.

If you want to perform an upload with a service account which is supposed to act on your behalf (that is upload a file to YOUR drive), you need to use [impersonation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegate-domain-wide-authority).

In java, when building `DRIVE_SERVICE`, you have to add the line

`.setServiceAccountId(emailAddress)`

specifying the email address of the user on whose behalf the service account is supposed to act (so in this case - your email address).